# Displaying the childs of a Linear layout in multiple lines

Tags: android, button, gridview, android-linearlayout

I have about 8 buttons under a horizontal linear layout. If I set the button width size as 50dp, then only 4 buttons are displaying and the some part of 5th button is displaying. I want to display these buttons as first four buttons in the one line and the other in the next line.

Please suggest me how I can do this. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Then use 2 Linear Layouts, one for each row of buttons.

Comment: I need them in the other buttons in the next line. I have 8 buttons so you are asking me to take 2 linear layouts. For suppose if I have 20 buttons. What will be the situation.

Comment: @KalyanUrimi my recommendation was strictly for for your specific problem, not a general one. In case you have to position many more buttons, I would suggest using [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply as I am generating these buttons dynamically, so I took 8 buttons as an example. Normally in my requirement I may not know the number of buttons.

Answer (score -1):

use [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) instead of LinearLayout .

Comment: Thanks for the reply @shailendra. I have used GridView for this but what happening is, now the buttons are not visible. I am adding buttons to this gridview dynamically in runtime.

Comment: probably you did not set layout params properly. please note that layout_width and layout_height are necessary attributes. share your code. thought i will recommend to add button through XML itself, untill you have specific reason of not doing that.